# How to move module under Mercurial to another VB.NET project?

Tags: vb.net, mercurial

Am using a single Mercurial repository to track my VB.NET 2010 solution myVBsolution. This contains 2 projects projectA & projectB. My module 'module1' is in projectA. The top of my mercurial repository is myVBsolution.

How do I move it to projectB in VB.NET. retaining change history for module1?

I have read that I need you need to use `hg mv` to perform the copy, but do not know the steps required to integrate the move with VB.NET.

The structure of code now:

```
myVBsolution
  projectA  
    -module1  
  projectB
```

Wanted:

```
myVBsolution
  projectA
  projectB
    -module1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the file using `hg mv` outside of Visual Studio. After that, in Visual Studio, remove the now missing file from `projectA` and use `Add->Existing Item` on `projectB` to add it to `projectB`.

---

But if you use [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), it's even easier: Just move the file in Visual Studio and use the [`Detect Renames`](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.3/guess.html) function of TortoiseHg (you can use 100% similarity).

Comment: I have TortoiseHg, so this seems a good idea - but I do not know how to do what you suggest: (1) how to move the file in Visual Studio (2) I cannot find `Detect Renames` in my TortoiseHg 2.1.0. How do I access it?

Comment: In Visual Studio, you can just drag and drop the file in the Solution Explorer. In TortoisHg, after you have moved the file, TortoiseHg will show the moved file twice: once in red with an `!` because for TortoiseHg it is missing, and once as a new file. Just right click one of these and select `Detect Renames` in the context menu.